# How to unwatch multiple repos easily on github?

Tags: github

I realize I watch too many repos in GitHub and the only way I've found to unwatch many of them is going to github.com/my_user_name/following, getting inside each of them and pressing Unwatch button.

Isn't there any way to unwatch them faster and easily?

Comment: There's an "Unwatch all" button at https://github.com/watching now.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

For the lazy, one can do this without the API reasonably quickly at this url: https://github.com/watching

A clean simple list, click click click click.

Additionally, there's a box that is golden. Uncheck it to not automatically be set to watch all repos you're given push access to. Hooray for managing the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: There's even a "Stop watching all repositories" button now!

Comment: Even without such a button, you could just open the developer console and do a quick `$('button').filter(function(){return $(this).text() === 'Unwatch'}).click()`. Web pages + jQuery = best API!

Comment: Thanks, @p11y , great idea. Here is an improved version with account filtering (if you just wish to filter certain organization's repos) ``$('button').filter(function(){return $(this).text() === 'Unwatch' && $(this).parent().parent().find("a span").html() == "organisationName" }).click();``

Comment: @Matej: would you mind posting this as an answer?  It also works great as a bookmarklet, which helps when the org is huge an has more repos than fit on a single page!

Comment: If you have multiple pages of watched repos, does the "Unwatch all" button unwatch *all* repos or just the ones on the current page?

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be on top. All these other answers be like "just create an app for that"

Answer (score 17):

Native JS version of [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912449/1541707). Navigate to https://github.com/watching and then run:

Oneliner:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.js-subscription-row')).forEach(el => { const org = el.querySelector('a[href^="/YOUR_ORG"]'); if (org) el.querySelector('button').click()})
```

Unwrapped:

```
const org = 'YOUR_ORG'
const query = document.querySelectorAll('.js-subscription-row')
const rows = Array.prototype.slice.apply(query)
rows.forEach(function (el) {
  const org = el.querySelector('a[href^="/' + org + '"]')
  if (org) el.querySelector('button').click()
})
```

Comment: The unwrapped version throws an error for defining the constant `org` more than once.

This works for me:

    const orgName = 'YOUR_ORG'
    const query = document.querySelectorAll('.js-subscription-row')
    const rows = Array.prototype.slice.apply(query)
    rows.forEach(function (el) {
      let org = el.querySelector('a[href^="/' + orgName + '"]')
      if (org) el.querySelector('button').click()
    })

Comment: The selectors have changed, what currently works is `Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.Box-row')).forEach(el => { const org = el.querySelector('a[href^="/alphagov"]'); if (org) el.querySelector('button').click()})`

Comment: Github seems to have updated this page. An update to the code above is this one that I just used: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.repo-list > li')).filter(el => !!el.querySelector('a[href^="/YOUR-ORG"]')).forEach(el => el.querySelector('details-menu button[value="included"]').click())` then just refresh the page and run it again until it's all done.

Comment: the most up-to-date version is being updated [here](https://gist.github.com/offirgolan/9b12a2a170f70d0d70e2238e8661e382)

Answer (score 10):

### Organisation specific

If you just want to unwatch repos from a single organisation, you can use this from https://github.com/watching

`$('.js-subscription-row').each(function(){
  var isYourOrganisation = $(this).find("a[href^='/YOUR_ORG']");
  if(isYourOrganisation.length){
    $(this).find('button:contains("Unwatch")').click();
  }
});`

Substitute `YOUR_ORG` with whatever your organisation is called.

Answer (score 2):

A few comments have mentioned the <kbd>Unwatch all</kbd> button at https://github.com/watching

Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: How do I undo this unwatching? Ie: resubscribe

Answer (score 2):

**Unwatch all** button on https://github.com/watching is available.

- [Unwatch all repositories owned by a given user or organization](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-12-unwatch-all-repositories-owned-by-a-given-user-or-organization/)

---

An alternative method is to use this script.

- https://github.com/yukihane/github-unwatch-repositories

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# dry run:
# ./github-unwatch.bash [unwatch repository pattern] [github account] [github token]
#
# execute actually:
# ./github-unwatch.bash [unwatch repository pattern] [github account] [github token] run

set -eu

readonly REPOSITORY_PATTERN="$1"
readonly CREDENTIALS="$2:$3"
readonly RUN="${4:-dry-run}"

page=1
targets=()

while :
do
  result=($( curl \
  -u $CREDENTIALS \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/user/subscriptions?per_page=100&page=$page" \
  | jq -r '.[].full_name' ))

  if [[ ${#result[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    break
  fi

  for e in "${result[@]}"
  do
    if [[ $e =~ $REPOSITORY_PATTERN ]]; then
      targets+=($e)
    fi
  done

  page=$((++page))
done

if [[ ${#targets[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
  exit 0
fi
for target in "${targets[@]}"
do
  echo "Unwatch: $target"
  if [[ "$RUN" == "run" ]]; then
    curl \
      -u $CREDENTIALS \
      -X DELETE \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
      "https://api.github.com/repos/$target/subscription"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Github has [an API](http://developer.github.com/v3/). You could write a script to do this using Github's API, particularly [the part that deals with watching repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/watching/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any but, As we have power of the entire universe(in short we are developers). Use their developer API and create a small tool. The API is very descriptive,

http://developer.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've also found a command-line tool that use the GitHub API to unwatch multiple repositories: https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-unwatch-org-repos

I'm not a fan of command-line tools that want my password in plain text on the command line (thus visible to all system users who run 'ps' at the right time, and also stored in plain text in ~/.bash_history unless you take extreme care to avoid that), so I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but this might be handy. The proposed solutions are little complex & few solutions doesn't allow you to specifically select an organization, etc.

```bash
# Make sure the personal access token has access to notifications & repo
GH_TOKEN=<TOKEN-HERE>
ORGANIZATION=<ORG-NAME>
MAX_REPO_COUNT=5000
repolist=$(GH_TOKEN=$GH_TOKEN gh repo list $ORGANIZATION -L $MAX_REPO_COUNT --json name --jq '.[].name')
echo $repolist | while read repo; do
  echo "Unsubscribing from $ORGANIZATION/$repo\n"
  GH_TOKEN=$GH_TOKEN gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /repos/$ORGANIZATION/$repo/subscription --method PUT -F ignored=true | jq '.'
done
```